# AX 2012 Group by with common table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How to group by a common table with a specific field?

I'm getting a syntax error on `(dt.fieldname2Id('BatchNo'))`

Here's my code:

```
Common          common;
SysDictTable    dt;

dt        =    SysDictTable::newName('Table1');
common    =    dt.makeRecord();

while select count(RecId) from common
    group by common.(dt.fieldname2Id('BatchNo'))  //syntax Error here
    where common.(dt.fieldname2Id('flag'))==1
{
    info(int642str(Common.Recid));
}
```

Comment: You can't do a `group by` with this method. You'll have to do what is suggested below.

Comment: @AlexKwitny Yup thanks, that worked. I have been trying all sorts of things with Common, trying to treat it like a normal buffer table object as I'm unable to find any good documentation on Common and other generic types. Please share if you know any.

Comment: Common is super useful, but I think the real issue is a limitation of the compiler's ability to parse the `select` statement and determine the `group by` field. I think it usually expects only the field name and not `Table.Field`. If I'm right, then it's technically impossible unless you use Macros to define every possible table and have it switching around at runtime (yuck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Query` instead:

```
Common                  common;
SysDictTable            dt;
Query                   query = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource    qbds; 
QueryRun                queryRun;

dt     = SysDictTable::newName('SalesTable');
common = dt.makeRecord();

qbds = query.addDataSource(common.TableId);
qbds.addGroupByField(dt.fieldname2Id('CustAccount'));

queryRun = new QueryRun(query);

while (queryRun.next())
{
    ...
}
```